# Electron-forge with webpack devServer

Tags: electron, webpack-dev-server, electron-forge, electron-webpack

I have created an app with electron-forge using `npx create-electron-app electron --template=webpack`.

I then did `npm install webpack-dev-server`

In my webpack.renderer.config.js I started to add a devServer section with `proxy` and `before` sections, but when I use `npm run start` these are ignored.

npm run start runs `electron-forge start` and that's where I think the problem is as I do not have direct access to the webpack call so as to get `webpack serve ...`

What is needed to get the webpack dev-server running with electron?

Answer (score 6):

`webpack-dev-server` is already used by `Electron-Forge`, as indicated in [Electron-forge Webpack documentation](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack)

> In development we spin up webpack-dev-server instances to power your renderer processes, in prod we just build the static files.

For renderer : it refresh for you.
For main, as indicated in the documentation, you have to type "rs" in the terminal to "reload" the app.

> For the main process, just type rs in the console you launched electron-forge from and we will restart your app for you with the new main process code.

If you want to access the webpack log server : http://localhost:9000/ (9000 is the default `loggerPort` in `plugins-webpack` config)

```js
// forge.config.js (or package.json)
 plugins: [
    ['@electron-forge/plugin-webpack',
      {
        // Renderer server port
        port: 3000,
        //  Webpack logger port
        loggerPort: 9000,
        mainConfig: './webpack...',
        ...
      }
     ],
```