# electron doesn't compile code after each change?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-forge

started an electron + react + typescript project a while ago and it was working fine, but then suddenly it stopped compiling after each change.

index.ts:

```
    import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
// This allows TypeScript to pick up the magic constants that's auto-generated by Forge's Webpack
// plugin that tells the Electron app where to look for the Webpack-bundled app code (depending on
// whether you're running in development or production).
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = (): void => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
    autoHideMenuBar: true
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);


  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

try {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
  require('electron-reloader')(module)
// eslint-disable-next-line no-empty
} catch (_) {}
// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

my package.json scripts:

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx ."
  }
```

If I cancel it and then try to run again my changes will be there. Also, this is a project where I code in different computers and with other people, and in other scenarios it is working fine, but in my case and in my computer it started to not work.

Answer (score 0):

With electron forge, your "renderer" will restart at each change but your "main" will not.

> Type "rs" into your console to get your main restart.

I already answer this question in this issue : [Electron-forge with webpack devServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904111/electron-forge-with-webpack-devserver/67370231#67370231)

Comment: I typed rs in the console and nothing happened, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Just found ''Not rewriting GET /main_window.77d71416238e5a5b9cbc.hot-update.json because the path includes a dot (.) character.'' on console in the port 9000. Could it be it?